# Make service self install in delphi

Tags: delphi, service

Does anyone know how to make service application in Delphi which install it self by running exe file.

Answer (score 28):

A Delphi service, created using the `TService` class, results in an executable that supports self-registration. Call it like this:

```
serviceexefilename.exe /install
```

Naturally you need elevated rights for this to work, just as you do for any mechanism that installs a service.

In the other direction use `/uninstall` to reverse the process. Use `/silent` to make the registration process, well, silent.

Should you wish to customise the installation process you can provide event handlers `BeforeInstall`, `AfterInstall`, `BeforeUninstall`, `AfterUninstall`. For example, a common use of `AfterInstall` is to supply a description for your service since the basic `TService` code does not.

Comment: +1 - didn't know that `TService` applications were automagically capable of this. So, if I'm understanding this right, can I use, for example, InnoSetup to start and register my application just by calling it with these parameters? Sweet!

Comment: Does the service also start itself after we run this self installation? Or do we need also to user `net start servicename` internally?

Comment: @EASI You'll need to start it, IIRC